# Creating a JSON table from 'aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups'

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq

I have a problem with parsing output/transforming it from ***aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups***

The output looks like this:

```
{
    "AutoScalingGroups": [
        {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-central-1::autoScalingGroup:854a8f05-cd3c-421d-abf3-0f3730d0b068:autoScalingGroupName/eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
            "LaunchTemplate": {
                "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "LaunchTemplateName": "eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
                "Version": "$Latest"
            },
            "MinSize": 1,
            "MaxSize": 6,
            "DesiredCapacity": 1,
            "DefaultCooldown": 300,
            "AvailabilityZones": [
                "eu-central-1a"
            ],
            "LoadBalancerNames": [],
            "TargetGroupARNs": [],
            "HealthCheckType": "EC2",
            "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300,
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "InstanceId": "i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1a",
                    "LifecycleState": "InService",
                    "HealthStatus": "Healthy",
                    "LaunchTemplate": {
                        "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                        "LaunchTemplateName": "eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
                        "Version": "1"
                    },
                    "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false
                }
            ],
            "CreatedTime": "2019-09-24T17:24:57.805Z",
            "SuspendedProcesses": [],
            "VPCZoneIdentifier": "subnet-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "EnabledMetrics": [],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "ResourceId": "eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
                    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
                },
                {
                    "ResourceId": "eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
                    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                    "Key": "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled",
                    "Value": "true",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
                },
                {
                    "ResourceId": "eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
                    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                    "Key": "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/k8s-team-sandbox",
                    "Value": "true",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
                },
                {
                    "ResourceId": "eks-nodegroup-AZ1",
                    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                    "Key": "kubernetes.io/cluster/k8s-team-sandbox",
                    "Value": "owned",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
                }
            ],
            "TerminationPolicies": [
                "Default"
            ],
            "NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn": false,
            "ServiceLinkedRoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling"
        },
        {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "eks-k8s-team-sandbox-AZ2",
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-central-1::autoScalingGroup:25324f3a-b911-453c-b316-46657e850b19:autoScalingGroupName/eks-nodegroup-AZ2",
            "LaunchTemplate": {
                "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "LaunchTemplateName": "eks-nodegroup-AZ2",
                "Version": "$Latest"
            },
            "MinSize": 1,
            "MaxSize": 6,
            "DesiredCapacity": 1,
            "DefaultCooldown": 300,
            "AvailabilityZones": [
                "eu-central-1b"
            ],
            "LoadBalancerNames": [],
            "TargetGroupARNs": [],
            "HealthCheckType": "EC2",
            "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300,
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "InstanceId": "i-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1b",
                    "LifecycleState": "InService",
                    "HealthStatus": "Healthy",
                    "LaunchTemplate": {
                        "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-XXXXXXXXXX",
                        "LaunchTemplateName": "eks-nodegroup-AZ2",
                        "Version": "1"
                    },
                    "ProtectedFromScaleIn": false
                }
            ],
            "CreatedTime": "2019-09-24T17:24:57.982Z",
            "SuspendedProcesses": [],
            "VPCZoneIdentifier": "subnet-XXXXXXXX",
            "EnabledMetrics": [],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "ResourceId": "eks-nodegroup-AZ2",
                    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "eks-nodegroup-AZ2",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
                },
                {
                    "ResourceId": "eks-nodegroup-AZ2",
                    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                    "Key": "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled",
                    "Value": "true",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
                },
                {
                    "ResourceId": "eks-nodegroup-AZ2",
                    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                    "Key": "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/k8s-team-sandbox",
                    "Value": "true",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
                },
                {
                    "ResourceId": "eks-nodegroup-AZ2",
                    "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
                    "Key": "kubernetes.io/cluster/k8s-team-sandbox",
                    "Value": "owned",
                    "PropagateAtLaunch": true
                }
            ],
            "TerminationPolicies": [
                "Default"
            ],
            "NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn": false,
            "ServiceLinkedRoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::ARN:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to parse it to get :

```
{
  "eks-nodegroup-AZ1" : "$DesiredCapacityForEks-nodegroup-AZ1",
  "eks-nodegroup-AZ2" : "$DesiredCapacityForEks-nodegroup-AZ2",
  "eks-nodegroup-AZ3" : "$DesiredCapacityForEks-nodegroup-AZ3",
  "eks-nodegroup-AZX" : "$DesiredCapacityForEks-nodegroup-AZX",
}
```

The following expected output will be used for external data resource for terraform to be able to automate DesiredCapacity value during the ASG rolling-updates.

Thanks, 
Dominik

Comment: sounds trivial, have you tried anything?

Comment: btw, for your consideration, there's also an _alternative_ approach to JSON manipulation in your question, based on unix _walk-path_ utility _jtc_: **`<response.json jtc -w'[AutoScalingGroupName]:<L>P:[-1][DesiredCapacity]' -T'{"{L}": {}}' -lljj`** it delivers the same result. If you like I can elaborate on it in a separate answer (I'm the developer of the `jtc` tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with your `response`,

```
response | jq '.AutoScalingGroups[] | {(.AutoScalingGroupName): .DesiredCapacity}' | jq -s add
```

Comment: If your question is resolved, then kindly ask you to accept the answer, please :)